# Coding for In/Out Tracking of Tools with no repeating and text always getting added into and not deleted text input by barcode scanner

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a code in Microsoft Excel Where it puts a text into a cell when another cell is filled in.

What I am looking for is that when cell A for example is filled cell C is filled in with OUT.  Then when cell A is filled in again on the next line or another line below it cell C on the same line as cell A is filled in with IN.

We would like to utilize a barcode scanner for checking the tools in and out.  I already figured out how to get the barcode to scan into column A

I would like this process to be repeated over and over again.

It's supposed to be a tracking sheet for when tools get taken out and get put back into stock.  The text is going to constantly be added and nothing deleted.    We want to utilize a barcode scanner to check tools in and out. The employees scan their barcode indicating them then they scan the tool indicating what tool they are taking. Then when they come back they scan their barcode again and then they scan the tool back into inventory. Of course just having this simple setup will lead to a mess of whether the tool is in or out and who used it last since we have a bunch of employees taking tools IN and OUT constantly.  That way we can be sure of who used what tool last and whether it's IN or OUT.

Below I have the coding that I need for the time stamp.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim B As Range, AC As Range, t As Range

Set B = Range("B:B")
Set AC = Range("A:A")
Set t = Target

If Intersect(t, AC) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Application.EnableEvents = False
Range("B" & t.Row).Value = Now
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Your revised title doesn't make any sense, either. Consider trying to describe the *specific* problem you're having. Dont' describe the application in detail just what is the specific and immediate problem.

Comment: Instead of `Now` (which is a function that returns the timestamp/date), use `"whatever text you want"`.

Comment: You don't need VBA for something this simple.  Paste the below formula in Cell C2, then copy it and paste it in all the "C" cells below C2.

=IF(AND((A2<>""), (C1="OUT")),"IN",IF(AND((A2<>""), (C1="IN")),"OUT",""))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a very contrived example for asking the question "In VBA, how do I fill an Excel cell with a specific string?"

The answer to that question is:

```
myRange.Value = "<myString>"
```

Anyway, this is how I would try to tackle your problem:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rngChange As Range
    Dim rngIntersect As Range
    Dim xlCell As Range
    Dim inOut As String

    Set rngChange = Range("A:A")
    Set rngIntersect = Intersect(Target, rngChange)

    If Not rngIntersect Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each xlCell In rngIntersect

            If xlCell.Value = "" Then
                inOut = "OUT"
            Else
                inOut = "IN"
            End If


            xlCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now
            xlCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = inOut
        Next xlCell
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End Sub
```

**Edit:**

In response to the asker's comments, the following modified code should address the problem:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rngChange As Range
    Dim rngIntersect As Range
    Dim inOut As String

    Set rngChange = Range("A:A")
    Set rngIntersect = Intersect(Target, rngChange)

    If Not rngIntersect Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False

            If rngIntersect.Row = 1 Then
                inOut = "OUT"
            ElseIf rngIntersect.Offset(-1, 2).Value = "OUT" Then
                inOut = "IN"
            Else
                inOut = "OUT"
            End If


            rngIntersect.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now
            rngIntersect.Offset(0, 2).Value = inOut
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End Sub
```

**Edit2:**

Use this to loop backwards through your log to determine the previous bookiung status for a specific id:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rngChange As Range
    Dim rngIntersect As Range
    Dim xlCell As Range
    Dim scanId As String
    Dim inOutOld As String
    Dim inOut As String

    Set rngChange = Range("A:A")
    Set rngIntersect = Intersect(Target, rngChange)

    If Not rngIntersect Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False

            scanId = rngIntersect.Value

            Set xlCell = rngIntersect

            If rngIntersect.Row = 1 Then
                inOut = "OUT"
            Else
                Do Until xlCell.Row = 1
                    Set xlCell = xlCell.Offset(-1, 0)

                    If xlCell.Value = scanId Then
                        inOutOld = xlCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
                        Exit Do
                    End If

                Loop

            End If

            If inOutOld = "IN" Then
                inOut = "OUT"
            Else
                inOut = "IN"
            End If

            rngIntersect.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now
            rngIntersect.Offset(0, 2).Value = inOut
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I am not subtracting text.  I am only adding it in.

Comment: @WhiteWolfman426 I am not sure if I understand your comment, please elaborate

Comment: Sorry not very good at explaining myself sometimes.  You see we want to utilize a barcode scanner to check tools in and out.  The employees scan their barcode indicating them then they scan the tool indicating what tool they are taking.  Then when they come back they scan their barcode again and then they scan the tool back into inventory.  Of course just having this simple setup will lead to a mess of whether the tool is in or out and who used it last since we have a bunch of employees taking tools in and out constantly.

Comment: That way we can be sure of who used what tool last and whether it's IN or OUT.

Comment: So cell C should be set to "IN" if it's current value is "OUT" and vice versa?

Comment: Or is the list only tracking a single, tool, keeping a sort of "log" for it? So records are appended to the current list?

Comment: Here is the things it's tracking multiple tools so the code setups must acknowledge the description which will be consistent with the barcode scanner and like you said if the value in cell C was "IN" last time it will input the text "Out" and vise versa but it must be consistent to multiple tools.  So if one person checked out a wrench, screwdriver and tire gauge.  Then regardless of what order he checks them back it should read "In" in column C next to each barcode reading of the tools.

Comment: When formulating a question, you should be as precise as possible, adding all relevant details. This keeps people from wasting their time answering questions based on wrong assumptions or incomplete information (please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I have updated my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using VBA, you could do this with a worksheet 'IF()' formula.

```
=IF(A3="","","OUT")
=IF(A4="","","IN")
```

To break it down, this means that if cell A3 = nothing ("") then put nothing ("") in cell C3, but if there is something in cell A3, then put "OUT".

Place the first formula in cell C3 and the second one in C4.  If the user of the tool inputs their initials/name in cell A3 then cell C3 will say OUT.  It's not until the user comes back and returns the tool and enters their initials/name in cell A4 that cell C4 will say IN.

Hope this simple, non-VBA, example helps!

Comment: Would that work the same way if the user input their initials into A5 since another personnel came and withdrew another tool?  Also,  what if they withdrew multiple tools?  On each one would it be out on all of them or just in and out consistently?

Comment: If I'm imagining your worksheet correctly, it consists of many tools and each tool is either 'in' or 'out'.  The two 'if' formulas above will need to be copied, as a set, to each tool on the spreadsheet.  I'm not sure what your worksheet exactly looks like, so you may need to edit my formula a bit.  Post an image if possible.

Comment: Well in short it's just three columns information is being entered into column A the time stamp is entered into column B and in column C I am hoping that once you put information in column A column C will indicate when it's out and when it's in.  The text isn't being deleted only added to the sheet.